# Find duplicate files in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, linux, hashcode

This code finds duplicate files in Linux. 
I assume that MD5 hash will return unique hash number.
What can I improve in this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python;

import sys
import subprocess
import os
import hashlib

FIND_CMD = "find . -name \*.* -print"
BUFFER = 65536

#Get path from the user
root_path = sys.argv[1]
#Checks that the user sent path
if not root_path:
 print("Error: No file specified.Please try again ")
 sys.exit(1)
#Chage working path
os.chdir(root_path)
#Get all the possible paths under the given directory
dirty_out = subprocess.run(FIND_CMD.split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
file_list = dirty_out.stdout.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
#Find files with the same size and add to dic
same_size = dict()
for file in file_list:
   path = root_path + file[1:]
   if os.path.isdir(path):
        continue
   if os.path.exists(path):
        file_size = os.path.getsize(path)
        #Add the path to dictionary by size
        if file_size not in same_size:
         same_size[file_size] = list([path])
        else:
         same_size[file_size].append(path)

#Find files with the same size and hash code
file_signatures = dict()
for size in same_size:
 if len (same_size[size]) > 1:
    i = 0
    while i < len (same_size[size]):
     # Hash file content with read buffer
     md5 = hashlib.md5()
     path = same_size[size][i]
     md5 = hashlib.md5()
     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                data = f.read(BUFFER)
                if not data:
                    break
                md5.update(data)
            md5_sig = md5.hexdigest()
            # Add to dictionary only files with the same size and hash
            if md5_sig not in file_signatures:
                file_signatures[md5_sig] = list([path])
            else:
                file_signatures[md5_sig].append(path)
     i=i+1
#Prints the path of all the duplicate files separated with , 
for sig in file_signatures:
    if len(file_signatures[sig]) > 1:
        print("{0}\n".format(",".join(file_signatures[sig])))
```

Comment: If you're not writing this for coding practice, you ought to be aware of the `rdfind` program, which does the same thing (and more).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please be careful with the indentation because it looks like there are different number of spaces for different indentation depths and it looks very weird.

Minor improvements:

#### Repetition

```
 md5 = hashlib.md5()
 path = same_size[size][i]
 md5 = hashlib.md5()
```

I am almost sure there is no reason to repeat `md5 = hashlib.md5()` twice.

#### "Native" iteration

```
while i < len (same_size[size]):
 # Hash file content with read buffer
 md5 = hashlib.md5()
 path = same_size[size][i]
 ...
 i=i+1
```

You are iterating over all the files with the given size:

```
for path in same_size[size]:
   ...
```

In general in Python you can use `for x in list_` to iterate over all items in any collection.

#### Zero length automatically skipped

```
if len (same_size[size]) > 1:
```

If you ask python to iterate over a zero length collection nothing happens, so you can remove this line as it does nothing but increases indentation and line count.

edit: No @miracle173 correctly noted that this is an efficiency gain to skip files of which there is only one of a certain size so it cannot be skipped.

#### Default dict to simplify logic

```
    if file_size not in same_size:
     same_size[file_size] = list([path])
    else:
     same_size[file_size].append(path)
```

Not tested, but using a `defaultdict` you can avoid the branch and only use `append`.

#### Same size?

Are you sure you need to calculate also the size in order to check if two files are equal? Isn't the hash enough?

Comment: "Same size" If there is only one file of a given size, this file cannot have a duplicate and you don't have to calculate the hash at all. This can save a lot of disk reads.

Comment: `if len (same_size[size]) > 1` does not mean to skip zero length lists of files of a given size but lists of length 1, so for this size exists only one file ans so there is no duplicate. so this if-clause cannot be skipped.

Comment: @miracle173 You are correct, answer edited

Answer (score 5):

1. The execution time of the program is determined by number of disk reads it has to make. So avoiding unnecessary disk reads by checking first if there is a file with the same size is a good thing. Maybe it makes sense, at least for large files, to calculate the hash only for a small part of the file. e.g. for the first BUFFER bytes, and you can avoid reading more of a file if no other file starts with the same BUFFER bytes. If it is possible to read blocks at any position of a file without reading all the blocks preceding this block, you should also use  blocks not only  from the beginning.
2. ```
   FIND_CMD = "find . -name \*.* -print"
   ```

   I don't understand why the first `*` is escaped by a `\` but the 2nd `*` is not.
3. Python has a way to list all files of a directory, so it is not necessary to exectute a shell command:

   > #### `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)`
   >
   > Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up.
4. The following code will not behave as you might expect:

   ```
   #Get path from the user
   root_path = sys.argv[1]
   #Checks that the user sent path
   if not root_path:
       print("Error: No file specified.Please try again ")
       sys.exit(1)`
   ```

   If no argument is supplied to the program then `sys.argv[1]` is not defined and an error is raised. So `print("Error: No file specified.Please try again ")` will never be printed.
5. Instead of

   ```
   if os.path.isdir(path):
       continue
   if os.path.exists(path):
       ...
   ```

   you can do

   ```
   if not os.path.isdir(path) and os.path.exists(path):
       ...
   ```

   and save an ugly `continue`.

   and a break used here

   ```
   while True:
       data = f.read(BUFFER)
       if not data:
           break
       md5.update(data)
   ```

   can be avoided this way

   ```
   data = f.read(BUFFER)
   while data:
       md5.update(data)
       data = f.read(BUFFER)
   ```

   But this is a matter of taste, of course.
6. What happens with `os.chdir(root_path)`, if root_path does not exist? You should not trust user input. You will get an exception. You should write an appropriate error message. Also for other OS-functions you should it may make sense to handle an error appropriate.
7. ```
       i = 0
       while i < len (same_size[size]):
           ...
           i=i+1
   ```

   isn't the way how such loops are handled in python.

   ```
   for i in range(len (same_size[size])):
       ....
   ```

   is the right way. In this special case [Caridorc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/202604/12462)  showed you an even better way.
8. In Unix like  sytems error messages should be printed to `stderr` and not to `stdout`. So ths is not the proper way to do this:

   ```
   if not root_path:
       print("Error: No file specified.Please try again ")
       sys.exit(1)
   ```

   A possible way to achieve this is

   ```
   if not root_path:
       sys.exit("Error: No file specified.Please try again ")
   ```
9. Your indentation is mixed. This is allowed but you should use alway the same indentation, preferable four spaces.